# How to compute curvature from chain code in image processing?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, discrete-mathematics, vision

How do I get from chart a (chain code) to chart b (curvature)?

0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 7, 6, 0, 0 --> 0, 2, -2, 1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From figure (a); the chain code comes out to be as follows:

[image: Chain Code of figure (a)]

According to [[2](https://books.google.com.my/books?id=DMmoCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA185&lpg=PA187#v=onepage&q&f=false)] - page 186; the curvature is calculated by toe following psuedo code:

```
c = d - di

for all di such that d remains within a limit of ±2 (critical point of a chain code)

if c < 2 then c+7
if c > 2 then c-7
```

So this gives the required result (b).

Reference: [Google Books](https://books.google.com.my/books?id=DMmoCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA185&lpg=PA187#v=onepage&q&f=false)